# RED5. Maven deploy issue

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, red5

I am trying to publish an spring mvc application in Red5Pro server. (tomcat).
I use Maven as build tool, but it seems to not work properly, because the
compiled classes are not found in WEB-INF/classes. This is my project structure:

[image]

The project is found in RED5ProHome/webapps, but without the compiled classes. (only xml, jsp and html).

This is my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.red5.example</groupId>
<artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<build>
    <finalName>springmvc</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
// all dependencies needed
</dependencies>
```

Another point is that I export my project as war, manually, it works.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the difference between your exported war and the maven war?

Comment: The maven war doesn't contain the .class files. It contains the folders, but these are empty.

Comment: I think your java source folder may be configured incorrectly. Ensure that the 'org.red5.examples.springmvc' are actually individual folders, something doesnt look right in your image.